# How to display result of df every 30s?

Tags: shell-script, df

All I want to see is the % after I issue `df /` every 30s but on the same line just after the previous number.

So the final output would be `86% 86% 86% 87% 87% ......`

Could it be one line code? Or multiple line 'program'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while printf '%s ' "$(df -P / | awk 'NR==2 { print $(NF-1) }')"; do
    sleep 30
done
echo
```

Comment: one-liner `while printf '%s ' "$(df -P / | awk 'NR==2 { print $(NF-1) }')"; do sleep 30; done` thank you

Comment: What would be syntax for alias? I cannot make it work... alias df2='while printf \'%s \' "$(df -P / | awk \'NR==2 { print $(NF-1) }\')"; do sleep 30; done' is not correct

Answer (score 24):

I'd prefer

```
watch -n 30 df
```

[Man watch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch):

> watch - execute a program periodically, showing output fullscreen

Comment: What is the advantage over my watch solution that at least only displays the root filesystem?

Comment: Upvoted because I didn't know that watch existed. But I don't think  your solution can deliver what I asked for.

Comment: @Radek I just asked because it seemed a copy of my answer coming in 9 minutes later as well showing even more that you did not want.

Comment: Your answer wasn't there when I started to write mine, I also edited my post a bit later and maybe it displays that time as the posting time. I certainly don't copy answers.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `watch`:

```
watch -n 30 -t df /
```

But that overwrites the existing output

Comment: You should read again what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

Crude, but works:

```
while true; do printf "%s " $(df / | awk '/root/ {print $5}'); sleep 30; done
```

Comment: Shouldn't be the text = inside to loop?

Comment: But this would be every 30s + execution time of df, right?

Comment: Made it a one-liner...

Comment: one-liner that can be run from a command line not from the script? If I copy&paste your code into command line and press enter it does nothing.

Comment: @Radek The `root` may be the problem. Adapt to your putput of `df /` or take my `NR==2`.

Comment: @Bernhard I think if someone cannot live with such an inaccuracy of about 1:3000 (on my system) then I would expect him to mention that in his question.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Thank you that helped. Now I have working one-liner! :-)

Comment: @Hauke Of course, I just wanted to be precise :)

Comment: Optional uglification:  `while( sleep 30 ) do ...`. Saves 5 chars at the cost of readability.

Comment: @Hennes Thanks: any uglification is good for me... :)

Answer (score 1):

For bash:

```
i=1
outputs_per_line=10
frequency=30
while true; do
  echo -n "$(df / | awk 'NR==2 {print $5}') "
  if [ $((i%outputs_per_line)) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo
  fi
  ((i++))
  sleep "$frequency"
done
```

The line break after $outputs_per_line numbers shall prevent a console line break within the output.

Comment: @Anthon If I had just made it `sleep 30` I might have been fast enough...

Comment: Interesting how your edit doesn't show up as a revision. I will delete my comment, now it seems inappropriate

Comment: @Anthon I assume there's a threshold of a few seconds or minutes below which revisioning is considered not useful.

Comment: That is probably it. I am not sure if your change was there before I commented. I would expect you were first, and that a comment would reduce the grace period for editing (to prevent these kind of discussions). I will browse meta (SO) to see if there is something.